# How to determine a page change with HTMLUnit?

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm looking for a smart way to determine if a web site has changed since I last ran a check with HTMLUnit against it.

I'm using HTMLUnit to scrape some values of a web page which fails from time to time because the page's layout has changed.
In these cases I want to get notified that the page looks different since my last visit.

I thought about persisting the page object that I get via HTMLUnit, by simply writing it to a file.
Next time I run my program, I could compare the fresh object with the persisted one.

Any opinions on this? Is there a smarter way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems no smarter way to deal with this, I did what I suggested in my question.
Getting the page, persisting the source and comparing this persisted html source with the fresh one next time I run the program.

The downside is that it doesn't work with some pages like google.com as they seem to create the page dynamically. Most other sites work though.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is interact with the new layout regardless of information on whether it was changed or not, try doing a `page.refresh()` or call `getPage()` again before executing any of your succeeding calls. Otherwise... well, I just looked into the [`HtmlPage` API](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html) and the feature you need doesn't seem to be built in to it as of now.

Comment: Well, not answering my question directly.
I visit the page once a day, so a page refresh doesn't help me.

Comment: Hm. Your question would be quite difficult to answer since we have no idea which parts of the HTML constantly change. Are you sure there are no consistent patterns in the changes that occur? Because if there is, your program's actions can depend on some conditionals. Also, exactly what do you want to do once you find out the page has changed? Continue scraping with the new elements in place or just send you an email that the HTML was changed?